# Analysis Challenge Question using Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $S=(\bar{x}_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^p$. Assume that $$ \left\|\bar{x}_{n+1}-\bar{x}_n\right\|_2 \leq \frac{1}{n!}\left\|\bar{x}_n-\bar{x}_{n-1}\right\|_2$$ for every natural number n $\geq$ 2. Prove that there exists a vector $\bar{a}\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{R}^p$ so that S converges to $\bar{a}$.

---

We are expected to first show that this is a Cauchy sequence and use the theorem to then say that is converges to some $\bar{a}\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{R}$. My professor also told us that we have to use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} = e-1$.

---

I've tried starting off by considering some $m,n\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{N}$ with $m,n\geq2$ and w.l.o.g. say that $m\geq n$.

Then consider $\left\|\bar{x}_m-\bar{x}_n\right\|_2 = \left\|\bar{x}_m-\bar{x}_{m-1}+\bar{x}_{m-1}-...-\bar{x}_{n+1}+\bar{x}_{n+1}-\bar{x}_n\right\|_2$
$$\leq \left\|\bar{x}_m-\bar{x}_{m-1}\right\|_2+\left\|\bar{x}_{m-1}-\bar{x}_{m-2}\right\|_2+...+\left\|\bar{x}_{n+2}-\bar{x}_{n+1}\right\|_2+\left\|\bar{x}_{n+1}-\bar{x}_n\right\|_2$$.

I then tried using the inequality above that relates the next to terms to the previous ones so that all the Euclidean norms above are reduced to the sum of the same Euclidean norm but with different coefficients:$$\leq \frac{1}{(m-1)!(m-2)!...(n+2)!(n+1)!}\left\|\bar{x}_{n+1}-\bar{x}_n\right\|_2+\frac{1}{(m-2)!(m-3)!...(n+2)!(n+1)!}\left\|\bar{x}_{n+1}-\bar{x}_n\right\|_2+...+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left\|\bar{x}_{n+1}-\bar{x}_n\right\|_2+\left\|\bar{x}_{n+1}-\bar{x}_n\right\|_2$$.

But this is where I'm not sure how to proceed, specifically with using the given convergent series to show that the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: Use the fact that $\frac 1{(m-1)!}+\frac 1 {m!}+..+\frac  1 {n!} \to 0$ as $n >m \to \infty$.

Comment: But I don't see how that uses the convergent series my professor told us to use.

Comment: He is saying that if $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n$ is convergent then $a_m+a_{m+1}+...  \to 0$ as $ m \to \infty$. That is a basic fact about convergence of series.

Comment: I know that, but it isn't using the equation that my professor said he wants us to use to solve it, he won't mark it as correct otherwise.

Comment: He is not asking you to use the exact value of $\sum 1/n!$. The value does not play any role here.

Comment: So what, he gave us the exact value just to mess with us?

Answer (score 1):

If $k>1$ and $\|x_{n+1}-x_n\|\le (1/k)\|x_n-x_{n-1}\|$ whenever $n\ge 2$ then by induction on $n\ge 2$ we have $$\|x_{n+1}-x_n\|\le (1/k^{n-1})\|x_2-x_1\|$$ whenever $n\ge 2.$

Now if $2\le a<b$ then $$\|x_a-x_b\|\le\sum_{j=0}^{b-a-1}\|x_{a+j}-x_{a+j+1}\|\le$$ $$\le \sum_{j=0}^{b-a-1}(1/k^{a+j-1})\|x_2-x_1\|\le $$ $$\le\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(1/k^{a+j-1})\|x_2-x_1\|=$$ $$=(1/k^{a-1})\frac {\|x_2-x_1\|}{k-1}.$$ So if $\epsilon >0$ and $n\ge 2$ is large enough that $(1/k^{n-1})\frac {\|x_2-x_1\|}{k-1}<\epsilon$ then $$n\le a<b\implies \|x_a-x_b\|\le (1/k^{a-1})\frac {\|x_2-x_1\|}{k-1}\le$$ $$\le (1/k^{n-1})\frac {\|x_2-x_1\|}{k-1}<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Kavi Rama Murthy in the comment section, if a series $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n} a_k \to 0$ as $m,n\to \infty$. Since
$$\sum\limits_{n>0}\frac{1}{n!} = e-1, $$
the series
$\frac{1}{(m-1)!}+\frac{1}{m!}+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}$ $\to 0$ as $m,n\to \infty$.
Now, as you have little bit noted down the iterarion process, can you prove the following?
$$ ||\overline{x_{n+1}} - \overline{x_n}||_2 \leq \frac{1}{n!(n-1)!\dots 2!}||\overline{x_2}-\overline{x_1}||_2\leq \frac{1}{n!}||\overline{x_2}-\overline{x_1}||_2.$$

It is now easy for us to show that the given sequence is Cauchy. Just observe that for $m>n$,
$$||\overline{x_m} - \overline{x_n}||_2 \leq \left(\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}\right)||\overline{x_2} - \overline{x_1}||_2.$$